# How to get list out of nested list and append using zip and map?

Tags: python

How to get list out of list?

```
list_ = [a,b,c]
```

I would like to get the variables out of nested list and append to lists

```
x = []
y = []
z = []
a = [[77,88,99],2,3,10]
b = [[100,101,102],5,6,11]
c = [[111,123,133],8,9,12]
list_ = [a,b,c]
w, x, y, z = map(list, zip(zip(list_)))
```

to receive:

```
x=[[77,88,99],[100,101,102],[111,123,133]]
y=[2,5,8]
z=[3,6,9]
v=[10,11,12]
```

it works if I would do:

```
w, x, y, z = map(list, zip(a,b,c))
```

but I would like to use list of lists `list_ = [a,b,c]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
w, x, y, z = map(list, zip(*list_))
```

You can use the unpack operator * to get the elements of a list.

Comment: Easy as that, thanks! Works well